# "Mein Herz Brennt" - Rammstein, what's the point?

Tags: rock, meaning, music-video

I have been listening to this song for quite a while, and I always have the same question in my head:
What is happening in the video ?

Where are they, what's the story, who's that weird monster, what's with children. Does it have story behind it ?

Link to this video I am talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXv31OmnKqQ

Any explanation ?

Comment: [Making of](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9_N94dZpdw)